# Packages is not working with pyinstaller. How to fix it?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-import

I have issues with imports and packages with pyinstaller.
So it's exception, that pyinstaller can't find package. I tried relative paths, gives exception about relative paths without parent package. everything works fine and all tests are passing if I run script via terminal.
Also I noticed that while compiling instead of path to my folder after modifying PYTHONPATH it prints D:\. I think changing this to my folder may fix this, but I didn't find way to do this. I even tried add path manually using system env variables, this didn't worked. Also my project contains __init__.py for every package, including main package. You can check structure of files here : https://github.com/farkon00/binarian.

Sorry for not including source code here, but it is too complecated, so I can`t post it here.

Comment: It sounds like the python path is not set up correctly. I'd recommend installing `pyinstaller` as well as all your package dependencies into a virtual environment, and running `pyinstaller` from within the venv.

Comment: @tdpu Still gives D:/

Comment: Once you've set up the venv, can you provide the output of `pip freeze`? Are you using Anaconda or some other env management system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it. So I used --paths and set it to my directory.
Command looks like this :

`pyinstaller binarian.py --paths "D:/binarian" --onefile --add-data "D:/binarian/std.bino;."`